# LDAP Query Distinct

Tags: ldap

is it possible to only list distinct values with an LDAP query?  I am getting duplicates of users for some reason but I only want them to be reported once, thank you for your help.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you provide an example of a query that returns user dupes?

Answer (score 3):

The directory model has no restriction on duplicate attribute values, including those attribute values which are part of an RDN. For example, the entry `uid=user1,dc=example,dc=com` and the entry `uid=user1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com` are two separate and distinct entries, yet the `uid` attribute is the same. Because of this, many professional quality directory servers implement some sort of uniqueness functionality that would enforce uniqueness of attributes.

In the event your directory server is not enforcing uniqueness, the way to return distinct values from an LDAP search request is to change the parameters of the search request, for example, use a different search base or filter to enable the directory server to distinguish entries that should be returned in the search response.

Answer (score 1):

I would be more concerned about why an LDAP query is returning users more than once, unless they exist more than once.  That would seem to indicate a real issue in your LDAP source.

That pretty much should not be happening.